# Iterate and filter a list using Java streams instead of for-each loop

Tags: java, lambda

In a kind of chat with a chatbot that I'm implementing, I have a List of Conversation and every Conversation has a List of Messages. I want to add those conversations that its last message is not a chatbot message and is not viewed by the user to a List of Conversations. To do that I'm coding it as bellow:

```
List<ConversationDto> conversationsToBeSent = new ArrayList<>();

for (ConversationDto conversation : super.allConversations) {
    if (conversation.getMessages() != null) {
        if (conversation.getMessages().get(0).getMessageType().getId() != MessageTypeEnum.CHATBOT.getValue()
                && conversation.getMessages().get(0).getToViewedAt() == null) {
            conversationsToBeSent.add(conversation);
        }
    }

}
```

This is working.
The question is how can I code that using Lambda and stream instead of for each.

Comment: Hi! Please show us what you've tried so far, so that we can see what you need help with

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is a classical **"Filter a collection"** task.
This is what the [`Stream.filter()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#filter-java.util.function.Predicate-) method does.

A code block:

```
List<Item> newList = new ArrayList<>();
for (Item item : collection) {
    if (predicate(item)) {
        newList.add(item);
    }
}
```

can generally be converted to:

```
List<Item> newList = 
    collection
        .stream()
        .filter(item -> predicate(item))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

In your case, the code transforms as follows.
Note the comments in the following code block for explanations:

```
List<ConversationDto> conversationsToBeSent = super.allConversations // Start with the original list
    .stream() // Get a stream of list items
    .filter(conversation -> // Filter the list items
        conversation.getMessages() != null
        && !conversation.getMessages().isEmpty() // YOU PROBABLY WANT THIS CHECK AS WELL!
        && conversation.getMessages().get(0).getMessageType().getId() != MessageTypeEnum.CHATBOT.getValue()
        && conversation.getMessages().get(0).getToViewedAt() == null
    )
    .collect(Collectors.toList()); // Collect the stream items to a new list
```

Answer (score 3):

To use stream on a list, just do `super.allConversations.stream()`
Then if you want to select only some elements, you can use the `filter` method like in the code below:

```java
super.allConversations.stream().filter(
  conversation ->
    conversion != null && 
    conversation.getMessages().get(0).getMessageType().getId() != MessageTypeEnum.CHATBOT.getValue() &&
    conversation.getMessages().get(0).getToViewedAt() == null
);
```